# Take in a char as an argument but return an int?

Tags: java

```
public class BookLab2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        BLab2Cons alph;
        char current;
        int index;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        alph = new BLab2Cons(26);
        String answer;
        System.out.println("Give me a sentence that ends with a period.");
        answer = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(alph.length);
        for (int x = 0; x < answer.length(); x++)
        {
            current = answer.charAt(x);
            index = answer.convertIndex(x); //This is where I am having problems.
        }
    }
}


public class BLab2Cons 
{
    int index;
    int alph[];
    char test;
    public int length;
    public BLab2Cons(int size)
    {
        alph = new int[size];
        length = alph.length;
    }
    public int convertIndex(char x) //The method that is not working.
    {
        index = (int)x - (int)'a';
        return index;
    }
}
```

This is the class where I make my methods, and if you test it out, convertIndex does not work. I have been trying for almost an hour now to try to get it to take in a char as an argument but return an int. I am not a very advanced coder so keeping it simple would be much obliged. I have tried to cast the char to an int, which seems to have worked, but when I need to actually use the method in my main code, it seems I always have to use a string as the argument rather than a char.

EDIT: this is the error I get: http://prntscr.com/e3tqsw

Comment: Use `alph.convertIndex(current)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not calling the method correctly. Currently, you have

```
index = answer.convertIndex(x);
```

but `convertIndex` is an instance method defined in your `BLab2Cons` class. Therefore, the method requires an instance of the class `BLab2Cons` in order to call it. Also, you're passing in `x` which is an `int` but your method is defined to take a `char` parameter. So the simple fix is to call the method using `alph` like so,

```
index = alph.convertIndex(current);
```

Comment: (; cheater hehe

Comment: Oh, I just changed the argument from x to current, because x is the integer in my for loop and the method calls for a char. The error is now gone and I will update this comment in a second if it is fixed/broken again. Thanks for saving me a huge headache oh my gosh

Comment: @ScaryWombat Seems like OP hasn't been on stackoverflow ever since his last comment but thank you, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 index = alph.convertIndex(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `current` to `convertIndex()`

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://prnt.sc/e3trmg), I think you may want to replace 'x' with 'current'